Proof that if $R$ is a strict partial order then $R$ is asymmetric
I'm proving the following statement in Velleman's How to Prove It (p. 210):

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Prove that if $R$ is a strict partial order then $R$ is asymmetric.

The proof is covered in the solutions, but it's a proof by contradiction different from mine. I've proceeded as follows:
Suppose $R$ is a strict partial order, i.e. $R$ is irreflexive and transitive. Transitivity implies that if $xRy$ and $yRx$ then $xRx$. But since by assumption $R$ is irreflexive, $\nexists x \in A : xRx$, so by modus tollens we conclude that either $\lnot(xRy)$ or $\lnot(yRx)$. This is equivalent to the statement that if $xRy$ then $\lnot(yRx)$. Since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, we conclude that $R$ is asymmetric. $\square$
Is my proof valid?

$\neg A$ or $B$ is indeed equivalent to $A\Rightarrow B$, so your proof is perfectly valid.

Great. Thank you!
